# AppEngine php UserService howto access specific user data

Tags: php, google-app-engine

On google appengine php app, the UserService that integrate the app with Google user accounts, the User class only have getter methods for user nickname and email ID, how then to get the user profile picture, user location, ...etc ?

Answer (score 1):

User service does not give you access to full user profile. The only piece of personal data is email.

You will need to use [OAuth login authorisation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) to [gain access to users profile](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#obtaininguserprofileinformation). There is a google-provided [OAuth2 client library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2) to make coding easier.